# Преобразовать "struct" из c++ в c#

Tags: c#, c++

Я конвертирую приложение с языка С++ на С#, но столкнулся с проблемой. Я не могу понять, как преобразовать эту структуру без потери ее функциональности.

```
struct point {
    ll x, y;
    int i;
} points[1000];
```

А также что может быть аналогом для

```
using ll = long long;
using ld = long double;
ll x, y; 

ll conv(ld x) {
    return ll(x * 1000 + 0.5l * (x >= 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5));
}
```

Полный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list> using namespace std;


using ll = long long; using ld = long double; ll x, y; 

struct point {
    ll x, y;
    int i; } points[1000];

ll conv(ld x) {
    return ll(x * 1000 + 0.5l * (x >= 0 ? 0.5 : -0.5)); }

bool lt(point& a, point& b) { 
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x < 0; }

int main() {
    int n, k = 0;
    ld a, b;

    cin >> a >> b >> n;
    x = conv(a), y = conv(b);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ld x, y;
        cin >> x >> y >> points[i].i;
        points[i].x = conv(x - a), points[i].y = conv(y - b);
    }


    sort(points, points + n, [](point& a, point& b) { return atan2(a.y, a.x) < atan2(b.y, b.x); });
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        if (lt(points[i], points[i + 1]))
            k = i + 1;

   cout << 0 << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       cout << points[(i + k) % n].i << std::endl;
    cout << 0 << std::endl; }
```

хотелось бы хотя бы пример для понимания

Comment: Зря не показали код, который вы начали переводить, минусов нахватали, потому что вопрос выглядит как "напишите за меня C# код пожалуйста, а то решение домашки нагуглил, но на C++, не знаю что делать дальше". К сожалению, здесь халяву не раздают, оплата принимается вашими собственными попытками решить задание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В С++ члены структур имеют видимость `public` по умолчанию, а в C# это нужно указать явно.
В C# принято наименования типов с большой буквы, поэтому `Point`, а не `point`.
Поля можно заменить на свойства, но это не обязательно.

```
struct Point
{
    public long x, y;
    public int i;
}
```

Ну и создаём массив структур:

```
Point[] points = new Point[1000];
```

Код самих вычислений переносится практически один в один.
Тригонометрические функции находятся в классе `Math`: `Math.Atan2`.
Сортировку можно выполнить методом `Array.Sort`.